# Docker CLI in Docker Desktop cannot find docker command

Tags: command-line, bash, docker

When I try to run simple docker commands(stop, restart) inside docker-CLI from docker-desktop (through the CLI icon on docker desktop), it gives me the error, `docker command not found`.
It gives me the same error even after starting bash through my gnome-terminal.

```
docker exec -it image-name /bin/sh
docker restart
docker command not found
```

I followed the installation guide on docker's official site and also on [this blog](https://blog.eldernode.com/install-and-access-docker-desktop-on-ubuntu-22-04/).

1. Installed Docker Engine
2. Installed Docker Desktop

My Image seems to run fine, but I cannot run any commands on docker CLI. I did add myself to the docker group. How do I troubleshoot this, I have Ubuntu 22?

Comment: Are you trying to run the command `docker restart` from inside a Docker container? Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can restart the docker engine using the following

```
docker exec -it image-name /bin/sh
exit
docker restart
```

In general, docker inside the docker is not a good idea.